# Minimal polynomial of composition of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

$Let$ $f:\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{2}[x],$ $f(g(x))=g'(x)-2g(x),$

$g(x)\epsilon\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$

$g'(x)$  the derivative of $g(x)$ and $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$ the subspace of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ spanned by the polynomials of maximum degree 2.

Find the minimal polynomial of $f$

Any ideas on how to work this out? Usually I find the characteristic polynomial of a linear transformation by creating the associated matrix but I have no idea how to do so here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try to write out what $f$ does to the "basis vectors" $1$, $x$ and $x^2$. If you represent these monomials as $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$, you can find the corresponding matrix.

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: For example: $f(x^2)=2x-2x^2$, so if you represent $1,x,x^2$ as $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$, then you see that the matrix $A$ associated to $f$ gives $A(0,0,1)^T=(0,2,-2)^T$. You can do the same for the other unit vectors and then you can find $A$.